# How would one go about proving this statement?

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Let n be a positive integer and let a1....an in the range [0,1] be real numbers. Show

$$1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_{i}}\leq \prod_{j=1}^{n}\left (1-a_{j}\right)$$

using induction. I've shown P(1) to be true. How would I prove the inductive step?

Comment: Which part of the inductive step are you struggling with? Perhaps show what you've done and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Now if we assume $1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i \leq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)$, let's start with RHS.

\begin{align}
\prod_{j = 1}^{n+1} (1 - a_j) &= \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right)(1 - a_{n+1}) \\
&= \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right)a_{n+1} \\
&\geq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - a_{n+1} \text{ because } (1 - a_j) \leq 1 \Rightarrow \left(\prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j)\right) \leq 1.
\end{align}

While LHS is just $1 - \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} a_i = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^n a_i - a_{n+1} \leq \prod_{j = 1}^{n} (1 - a_j) - a_{n+1}$. So now you can combine both parts and complete the induction.